# merge pdf from folder and sort by name with python / the outcome is not same as the folder order

Tags: python, pdf

this code combine pdf perfectly but the outcome order is not the same as the order in the source folder:

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger

def combine_pdfs_from_folder(input_folder, output_path):
    pdf_merger = PdfMerger()

    for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            pdf_merger.append(os.path.join(input_folder, filename))

    with open(output_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        pdf_merger.write(output_file)

    print("PDF files combined successfully.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_folder = 'E:\SRPlabel - 116843_C_3s'
    output_path = 'C:/tempo/merged.pdf'

    combine_pdfs_from_folder(input_folder, output_path)
```

my issue is that the outcome is not sorted in the same order inside the source folder which looks like that;

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
  import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger

def extract_numeric_prefix(filename):
    return int(filename.split('-')[0])

def combine_pdfs_from_folder(input_folder, output_path):
    pdf_merger = PdfMerger()

    # Get a list of PDF filenames and sort them numerically
    pdf_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(input_folder) if filename.endswith('.pdf')]
    pdf_files.sort(key=extract_numeric_prefix)

    for filename in pdf_files:
        pdf_merger.append(os.path.join(input_folder, filename))

    with open(output_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        pdf_merger.write(output_file)

    print("PDF files combined and sorted successfully.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_folder = r'.\SRPlabel - 116843_C_3s'  # Use a raw string
    output_path = os.path.join('.', 'tempo', 'merged.pdf')  # Use os.path.join()

    combine_pdfs_from_folder(input_folder, output_path)
```